# Error with polymer build

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am triying to learn how to use the new app-toolbox. In local, works fine; but when I use:

```
polymer build
```

I get these errors:

> C:\Users\Marcos\Documents\poly2>polymer build
>   info:    Building application...
>   info:    Generating build/unbundled...
>   info:    Generating build/bundled...
>   error:   Uncaught exception: Error: file path is not in root: C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/poly2/index.html (C:\Users\Marcos\Documents\poly2)
>   error:   Error: file path is not in root: C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/poly2/index.html (C:\Users\Marcos\Documents\poly2)
>       at StreamAnalyzer.urlFromPath (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\lib\build\analyzer.js:91:19)
>       at StreamAnalyzer.addFile (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\lib\build\analyzer.js:81:29)
>       at StreamAnalyzer._transform (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\lib\build\analyzer.js:48:14)
>       at StreamAnalyzer.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
>       at StreamAnalyzer.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
>       at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
>       at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
>       at StreamAnalyzer.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:215:11)
>       at PassThrough.ondata (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:531:20)
>       at emitOne (events.js:95:20)

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Deleting npm-cache at `C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and re-installing nodejs and polymer-cli fixed this for me.
Currently, I'm using Windows 10 with nodejs `v4.4.5`, npm `v2.15.5` and polymer-cli `v0.11.0` (I notice that they've just updated polymer-cli from `v0.10.0` to `v0.11.0`)

Hope this help.