# Error building polymer project with google-signin

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, google-signin, vulcanize

Frankly, I'm not sure how to reproduce this error. What I know is that somewhere in the build, I get the following message:

```
debug:   accept: ../../../../../../bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.css
error:   Promise rejection: Error: file path is not in root: /bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.css (/path/to/project/root)
error:   Error: file path is not in root: /bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.css (/path/to/project/root)
    at Object.urlFromPath (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/path-transformers.js:41:15)
    at StreamAnalyzer.getFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:107:39)
    at StreamResolver.accept (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:210:34)
    at FileLoader.request (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/hydrolysis/lib/loader/file-loader.js:64:27)
    at Vulcan.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:377:26)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Vulcan.inlineCss (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:365:33)
    at Vulcan.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/vulcanize/lib/vulcan.js:486:21)
```

The number of `../`s corresponds to the depth of my project root, i.e., the absolute path it is searching for is `/bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.css`. If I move the project to a different directory at a different depth, it changes accordingly.

The error depends solely on this line in my custom element for the main app container (i.e., exactly one instance of it lives in the `index.html` file and it is a direct child of `<body>`):

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.html">
```

I've commented out all uses of `<google-signin>`, but the error still exists. I've put it in every position within the imports section of my code. If I comment out that line, the build succeeds.

I created a new project using the starter kit and added a `<google-signin>` element to it. Building *that* project passed. I copied the `bower_components` folder from that project into my own. The build still failed.

Searching for solutions, I found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500431/error-with-polymer-build) and tried it to no avail.

I've used `nodejs` and `bower` from both `npm` as well as my operating system's package manager.

I should also note that the application is fully functional within the development server, e.g., `polymer serve --open`.

I've posted my `bower` dependencies below. My system is running Arch Linux and the last full system update was yesterday. The build was not working before the update, either.

```
{
  "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
  "description": "Web Front-end for PROJECT_NAME",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.10",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.7",
    "app-elements": "PolymerElements/app-elements#^0.10.1",
    "google-signin": "GoogleWebComponents/google-signin#^1.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Further, here is a complete list of imports used by the file:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `polymer.json` file did not contain all of the necessary `fragments`, and this was causing the error.